# NullReferenceException Can't figure out what's Null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I get this error in Unity:

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
TowerSlot.OnGUI () (at Assets/TowerSlot.cs:26)

I'm relatively new to Unity and can't figure out what line this error is from(I'm assuming 26) and I don't know what is null. If someone could please help explain to me how to understand what the error is pointing at and what I need to do it would be much appreciated.

TowerSlot.cs:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TowerSlot : MonoBehaviour {
    public GUISkin skin = null;

    bool gui = false;

    // Tower prefab
    public Tower towerPrefab = null;

    void OnGUI() {    
        if (gui) {
            GUI.skin = skin;

            // get 3d position on screen        
            Vector3 v = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(transform.position);

            // convert to gui coordinates
            v = new Vector2(v.x, Screen.height - v.y); 

            // creation menu for tower
            int width = 200;
            int height = 40;
            Rect r = new Rect(v.x - width / 2, v.y - height / 2, width, height);
            GUI.contentColor = (Player.gold >= towerPrefab.buildPrice ? Color.green : Color.red);
            GUI.Box(r, "Build " + towerPrefab.name + "(" + towerPrefab.buildPrice + " gold)");

            // mouse not down anymore and mouse over the box? then build the tower                
            if (Event.current.type == EventType.MouseUp && 
                r.Contains(Event.current.mousePosition) &&
                Player.gold >= towerPrefab.buildPrice) {
                // decrease gold
                Player.gold -= towerPrefab.buildPrice;

                // instantiate
                Instantiate(towerPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);

                // disable gameobject
                gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnMouseDown() {
        gui = true;
    }


    public void OnMouseUp() {
        gui = false;
    }
}
```

Also I'm trying to follow this tutorial here http://makeagame.info/unity-tower-defense-game-step-4-scripting

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot in OP's reply to @Hatchet definitely shows the tower prefab has not been set in the editor.

Either it's supposed to be set by some other code (which is not working) or it should be set manually.  You can do this by dragging a tower prefab onto the slot, or by clicking on the little circle to the right of 'None (Tower)': That'll pop up a picker dialog where you can choose a tower prefab.  It shows up as 'Tower' because that's the kind of variable it wants.

BTW the GUIskin is also not set. That will probably cause a problem when you hit the line

```
GUI.skin = skin;
```

Docs on the Unity gui for assigning references like this are here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/EditingReferenceProperties.html

Answer (score 2):

You set `towerPrefab` to null early on, and then on line 26, you reference its `buildPrice` property or field before assigning it any non-null value. That will throw a null exception.

This line is the problem:

```
GUI.contentColor = (Player.gold >= towerPrefab.buildPrice ? Color.green : Color.red);
```

Comment: The public tower towerPrefab = null is creating a public property in Unity. OP has probably forgotten to assign a value to it in the Unity editor - not in the code.

Comment: @theodox - I looked too briefly, and was thinking the towerPrefab was a local var in the method. I still think towerPrefab is what's null. It is not getting set to non-null before that line is executed.

Comment: This is what I see in the unity editor http://gyazo.com/90166d36a096ee0953d5f4f386d32c0c if I try and add something else the assets and scene appear as empty. Have I assigned it or not? I'm not sure because it says the name of the prefab in brackets after none...

Answer (score 0):

**hatchet** has pointed the problem. I think this may fix it:

```
public Tower towerPrefab = new Tower();
```

Because `Tower` class has the the property `buildPrice` which you are trying to access.

Comment: I tried that and got the same null error as well as two warnings: You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent().  Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all
 AND You are trying to create a MonoBehaviour using the 'new' keyword.  This is not allowed.  MonoBehaviours can only be added using AddComponent().  Alternatively, your script can inherit from ScriptableObject or no base class at all
UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:.ctor()
Tower:.ctor()
TowerSlot:.ctor()